# Wiki sharing between Sharepoint and Teams

Tags: office-365, wiki, microsoft-teams

I would like to create a wiki in Microsoft Teams and have it viewable in Sharepoint (or vice versa).  Is this possible?

I have created wikis in Teams, and then they show up as something like *.mht* files in the Sharepoint documents directory (writing this from memory, so I might have slightly incorrect terminology), but they aren't actually viewable as a wiki page; Sharepoint wants to download the file when clicked on.

As for the inverse process (create in Sharepoint ➝ view in Teams), I haven't been able to get anything to work.

Comment: Rather than using OneNote, can we use the SharePoint Wiki library? I find the Teams Wiki unfriendly.

Answer (score 2):

As for your approach you are right I think. Creating content in Microsoft Teams Wiki means it gets stored in underlaying SharePoint Online site in library "Teams Wiki Data" as .mht files. You can open them in SharePoint Online by click, but they will sadly open in your client software "Microsoft Word".

**How we solve sharing information between "Microsoft Teams" and connected "SharePoint Online Site"**

As you know - creating a team in Teams means there will be created a SharePoint Online site with same permissions. This is the technical base of storing data in this team.

With the site a "Notebook" is created. This is a OneNote notebook and this can be used in both worlds - in SPO and Teams.

To use this for storing information as you would do in "Wiki" just add a tab to your team channel by clicking the + symbol.

[image]

Then choose OneNote as app to add.

[image]

Choose "browse notebooks" to get a selection of OneNote notebooks on your connected SharePoint Online site. Select the notebook you want to use in Teams and SPO for storing information.

[image]

OneNote provides the same functionality as the Wiki tab in Teams and gives you the desired option to be used in both worlds without problems.

**Maybe this helps you out. Would be pleased if you marked this as answer if this helps.**

Comment: This did not work for me in either direction.  I added content to the existing Notebook in the SPO site.  I tried to add a OneNote to my Team as you described, but there is no option to "Browse notebooks".  Going the other way, I add a new OneNote notebook to my Team, but it's nowhere to be found when I browse the Sharepoint site's "Notebooks" section.

Comment: If there is no "Browse notebooks" option I am stumped. You will need this option to achieve what I described in my answer.

Comment: Worked, though the only way I could find to add it to my OneNote App was to use the Open in App option in Sharepoint.

Comment: "OneNote provides the same functionality as the Wiki tab in Teams..." to the extent that this is true, it is ONLY because the "Teams Wiki" really is no Wiki. Shame on Microsoft for their continued abuse of the term "Wiki". See Fulltextsearch for Teams Wiki:

https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/18623599-fulltextsearch-for-wiki